# Swift: How to convert vertical UIScrollView to a horizontal one

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

Usually, I would use SwiftUI's `ScrollView`, but in my edge case scenario, I need to use it as a `UIScrollView` in SwiftUI's `UIViewRepresentable`

```
struct CALayerScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
    var view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2))
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    let scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()

        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 10

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let blueView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    let greenView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1200).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
            scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)
            scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(redView)
            scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
            scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenView)

            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

            scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            // this is important for scrolling
            scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        

    return view
       
}
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
}
```

I've tried setting the viewAxis to `.horizontal`, but I still does not scroll laterally.

Any advices is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the stack view axis to **Vertical** -- but you want **Horizontal** scrolling... so set it to `.horizontal`.

You are setting **Height** for each arranged subview, but you haven't set the **Widths**... so give them Widths.

You should constrain the scroll view's **content** to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide**.

Because you're setting varying Heights, it's not quite clear if you want **only** horizontal scrolling... so this example ends up scrolling both directions:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            CALayerScrollView()
        }
        .frame(width: 240, height: 400)
        .background(Color.yellow)

    }
}

struct CALayerScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2))
        
        let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
            let scrollView = UIScrollView()
            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return scrollView
        }()
        
        let scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
            let view = UIStackView()
            
            // Horizontal Stack View
            view.axis = .horizontal
            view.spacing = 10
            
            // .top Alignment, because we're setting different heights for the subviews
            view.alignment = .top
            
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return view
        }()
        
        let redView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
            // also needs a width
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            return view
        }()
        
        let blueView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            // also needs a width
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
            view.backgroundColor = .blue
            return view
        }()
        
        let greenView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1200).isActive = true
            // also needs a width
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800).isActive = true
            view.backgroundColor = .green
            return view
        }()
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(redView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenView)
        
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // we want to constrain the scroll view *content* to the Content Layout Guide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return view
        
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
}
```

Should get you on your way...